# Refinery cms with mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I am running command..

```
 $ refinerycms rickrockstar -d=mysql -U=root -P=root
```

and getting error like this..

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). 
 Please provide the root password for your mysql installation
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: refinerycms myapp -d mysql -u mydbuser -p mydbpassword - try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$refinerycms rickrockstar -d=mysql -U=root -Proot
```